# Want to fetch the RSS feed and render on the html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, rss

I am trying to render this url http://online.wsj.com/xml/rss/3_7085.xml to fetch all the xml information using jquery but i came across something on jsonp thats giving me a callback ,how do i handle that callback to render each node in the html.

I tried the below code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>RSS Feed testing</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var result;
    function jsonparser1() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://online.wsj.com/xml/rss/3_7085.xml",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (result) {
               $("div").html(result);
               
            },
        });
    }        
 
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
        jsonparser1();
    });
</script>    
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I googled, about jsonp ,its quite confusing to me.

Comment: Unless wsj has CORS enabled, it is not going to happen because of the Same Origin Policy and you can not make JSONP just happen, the server you are calling has to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Rss feed in xml format. Use datatype = json.

```
function jsonparser1() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://online.wsj.com/xml/rss/3_7085.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (result) {
           $("div").html(result);

        },
    });
}
```

Comment: The rss is in xml node, i tried all the datatype=json or jsonp or xml but no result. On a Note its a xml format, why would i write json as datatype??

Comment: This won't work, because of CSP as explained in the comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not doable directly. You need to use a service like [Superfeedr's Feed API](http://blog.superfeedr.com/jquery-superfeedr/) or [Google's](https://developers.google.com/feed/).

These services will serve your the content of the feed in JSON using JSONP so that you can easily integrate any feed into any page.